# Bandwidth Cap Guest Wi-Fi to 75 GB?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt, bandwidth, pfsense

I need to set a bandwidth cap on my guest Wi-Fi. I am not trying to limit the bandwidth speed, I already know how to do that, that's not what I'm asking for.

I need to cap them after 75 GB, I need to either cut them off, or give them 756 Kbps down and 256 Kbps up. I'm trying to do this because my ISP caps me at 250 GB per month, and I'm getting sick of them using up all the bandwidth and then where stuck at 1 Mbps down and 512 Kbps up for the rest of the month, that sucks.

I would like them to download full blast until they use up there 75 GB per month, then cut them off, or something.

My router is a old dual core computer with *pfsense*, and the access point is a *TP-Link* router with dd-wrt installed on it. Thanks in advance for any help! :-)

Comment: "_I need to set a bandwidth cap on my guest Wi-Fi. I am not trying to limit the bandwidth speed, I already know how to do that, that's not what I'm asking for._" Bandwidth _is_ the maximum speed a link can do, measured in bps. "_I need to cap them after 75 GB_" That has nothing to do with bandwidth; that is data usage, a very different subject.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are running pfSense, it's time for you to figure out the "captive portal" which is the built-in method of doing what you want (or at least what I think you want) on pfSense.

https://forum.pfsense.org/index.php?board=2.0

Or perhaps better (limiting data **amount** does seem to require getting FreeRADIUS up and running as well):

https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Using_Captive_Portal_with_FreeRADIUS

Personally I don't feel your level of obligation to guest users - if they can check their email, I've done all I really feel is needed. I have no compunctions about throttling them so they stay out of the way of users.

Answer (score -1):

You can limit their bandwidth to 75 GB / 30.4 days / 24 hours / 60 minutes / 60 seconds = 28.5 KB/s so even if they use 100% bandwidth 100% of the time, then they can never use up more than 75 GB in the month.